# Incorrect Syntax Near The Keyword 'INTO' , Can't we use Temporary Table?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to insert the values that are being selected from other query , this other query internally uses temp table but i'm facing an error Incorrect Syntax Near The Keyword 'INTO'

I cannot share the actual code but it looks something similar to below . Please help .

Can't we use temporary table inside values

for example

```
Insert Into Customer(
Name ,
OrderId)

Values ( @Name ,
Select SalesId INTO #temp
From Sales
Left Join

Select Orderid
from order

on sales.salesid = order.Orderid

where SalesId In (Select Top 1000 orderid from #temp)

Drop table #temp))
```

Comment: So, the question is related to `c#` how?

Comment: Not the way you are doing it now. What are you trying do here?  You can break it up into separate steps, but what is the goal here?  and the rest of your syntax is not right

Comment: You cannot have `Values` and a `Select` statement for an Insert, just select the values you want to insert.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems arbitrary to insert 1000 Customers with the same name for only the first 1000 sales records, but I think (?) this is what you want to do:

```
INSERT INTO Customer(Name, OrderId)
    SELECT TOP 1000 @Name, o.Orderid 
    FROM Sales s
    LEFT JOIN [order] o
        ON s.salesid = o.Orderid
    WHERE o.Orderid IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but an insert like this should take the form:

```
insert into Customer (Name, OrderId) 
select @Name, SalesId
  from Sales s
  left join (
    select Orderid
    from order
  ) a on s.salesid = a.Orderid
  where s.SalesId In (select Top 1000 orderid from #temp)
)
```

Comment: Your left join needs an alias